# How to run a TestNG batch file from an HTML page

Tags: javascript, batch-file, ant, automation, testng

The below code runs a simple batch file to echo something, but doesn't run the testNG.bat.

The batch file has four commands: ANT, clean, compile and run

```
<html>
    <!--Javascript to run batch file as an Active X component in IE-->
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        MyObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
        function Runbat() {
            MyObject.Run("\"D:\\testNG.bat\"");
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <h1>Run a Program</h1>
        <button onclick="Runbat()">Run bat File</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Untested**

I would have tried like this:

```
MyObject.Run("\"file:///D:/testNG.bat\"");
```

or at least like this:

```
MyObject.Run("\"D:/testNG.bat\"");
```

If it does not work, try replacing escaped quotes with single quotes ( `\"` by `'` )

Comment: Thanks. Both of the above cases work good. But Actual issue is: Batch file launched via web and by double click shows different paths. Any suggestions?

Comment: @vinaykumar Just a guess, probably a security issue in IE settings?

Comment: Had to add a 'cd "path"' command in batch file', then worked flawlessly. Thanks again.